# Joining two MySQL tables correctly based on conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

My database has the following two tables

jobs:

```
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Mechanic     |
|  2 | Programmer   |
|  3 | Cleaner      |
|  4 | Truck driver |
+----+--------------+
```

qualifications:

```
+--------+--------------------+
| job_id | qualification      |
+--------+--------------------+
|      1 | drivers_license    |
|      1 | engine_certificate |
|      2 | mysql_certificate  |
|      4 | drivers_license    |
+--------+--------------------+
```

Let's say that I have a drivers_license and a mysql_certificate. I want to create an SQL query that returns all jobs that don't have requirement I don't have. So the result of the query should be job id 2, 3 and 4.

I have tried the following query:

```
select * 
  from jobs j
  join qualifications q
    on j.id = q.job_id 
 where q.qualification = 'drivers_license' || 
q.qualification = 'mysql_certificate';
```

This returns id 1, 2 and 4 and therefore obviously doesn't work.

How can this be achieved in SQL? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select j.name, j.id
from jobs j join
     qualifications q
     on j.id = q.job_id 
group by j.name, j.id
having sum(q.qualification not in ('drivers_license' , 'mysql_certificate')) = 0;
```